# Tag synonym request; [erd] -> [erd-diagrams] -> [er-diagram]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms, retag-request

We currently have [er-diagram](/questions/tagged/er-diagram) (9 questions), [er-diagrams](/questions/tagged/er-diagrams) (2 questions) and [erd](/questions/tagged/erd) (118 questions); all covering the same topic of Entity Relationship Diagrams.

I propose that [er-diagram](/questions/tagged/er-diagram) becomes the root, as it is easier to understand at a glance than [erd](/questions/tagged/erd).

Comment: Just a question for me, because I can't understand it, why did you approve the edits if you think those tags should vanish?

Comment: @Asylum: I accepted the first two (for the [tag:erd] tag), and *then* saw the duplicates edits for the other tags.

Comment: Aahhh...Id didn't see the other rejections, sorry, my mistake.

Comment: Just a note: Synonyms on SE sites are not hierarchical.